# Progress bar for rforcecom.checkbatchstatus()

Tags: r, user-interface, salesforce, progress-bar

I am asking to write a text or graphical progress tracker while rforcecom's batch update function loads batches of up to 10,000.

To set up and complete a batch update, a few objects must be created--there is no avoiding it. I *really* do not like having to re-run code in order to check the status of rforcecom.checkBatchStatus(). This needs to be automated while a progress bar gives a visual of actual progress, since checking in the global environment isn't preferred and it will be a static "status" update until it's run again.

Here's how the code is set up:

```
require(Rforcecom)
## Login to Salesforce using your username and password token
## Once ready to update records, use the following:

job<- rforcecom.createBulkJob(session, operation = 'update',        
   object = 'custom_object__c')
info<- rforcecom.createBulkBatch(session, jobId = job$id, data = entry, 
   batchSize = 10000)
### Re-run this line if status(in global environment) is "In Progress" for     
### updated status
status<- lapply(info, FUN = function(x) { 
   rforcecom.checkBatchStatus(session, jobId = x$jobId, batchId = x$id)})
###Once complete, check details
details<- lapply(status, FUN = function(x){ 
   rforcecom.getBatchDetails(session, jobId = x$jobId, batchId = x$id)})    
close<- rforcecom.closeBulkJob(session, jobId = job$id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate re-running the status code, use the repeat loop:

```
repeat {
   statements...
   if (condition) {
      break
   }
}
```

Then, to get a visual for a progress update, use the txtProgressBar() in base R. For this particular function, I made my own progress bar function with two simple companion functions. As a note about progressValue(), the rforcecom.checkBatchStatus() outputs as a list of 1 and a sublist. The sublist name for checking the number of records processed is "numberRecordsProcessed".

```
progressBar<- function(x, start = 0, finish){
   # x is your object that is performing a function over a varying time length
   # finish is your number of rows of data your function is processing
   pb <- txtProgressBar(min = start, max = finish, style = 3)
   for (i in 1:finish){
      i<- progressValue(x)
      setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
      if (progressValue(x)/finish == 1) {
         close(pb)
      }
   }
}

finish<- function(x){
  return(as.numeric(nrow(x)))
}

progressValue<- function(x){
   x=x[[1]][["numberRecordsProcessed"]]
   return(as.numeric(x))
}
```

Now, bring it all together! Repeat loops can be trained to end as long as you know your conditions: "Completed" or "Failed". Repeat "status", which will update the number of records processed, and by doing so this will update your progress bar. When the number of records processed equals the number of rows in your data, the progress bar will quit and so will your repeat loop.

```
repeat { 
   status<- lapply(info, FUN = function(x){
      rforcecom.checkBatchStatus(session, jobId = x$jobId, batchId = x$id)})
   progressBar(status, finish = finish(entry))
   if (status[[1]][["state"]]=="Completed") {
      break
   }
   if (status[[1]][["state"]]=="Failed") {
      break
   }
}
```